# How to remove header from pandas Styler?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

I want to remove the header from the pandas Styler so that I can render it.
What I have tried:

```
def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: #f5f5dc'
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1.loc[['A'], :] = c1
    return df1
temp = {'col1': ['abc', 'def'], 'col2': [1.0, 2.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(temp)
df.index = ['A', 'B']
print(df)
df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None).hide_index()
```

Output

```
col1  col2
-------------
abc   1.000000
def   2.000000
```

But I want to remove col1 and col2 as it comes in my post rendering page which I don't need.

Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas 1.4.0 both [`hide_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_index.html) and [`hide_columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_columns.html) were deprecated ([GH43758](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43758)) in favour of [`hide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html) with `axis=...`

With labels:

```
df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None).hide(axis='index').hide(axis='columns')
```

With axis numbers:

```
df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None).hide(axis=0).hide(axis=1)
```

[image: styled table with no index or columns]

---

In versions prior to 1.4.0 the [`hide_columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_columns.html) function can be used to hide the columns. Similar to how the [`hide_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_index.html) function does for the index:

```
df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None).hide_index().hide_columns()
```

[image: styled table with no index or columns]